# How to extract and use BERT encodings of sentences for Text similarity among sentences. (PyTorch/Tensorflow)

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, nlp, pytorch, bert-language-model

I want to make a text similarity model which I tend to use for FAQ finding and other methods to get the most related text. I want to use the highly optimised `BERT` model for this NLP task .I tend to use the the encodings of all the sentences to get a similarity matrix using the `cosine_similarity` and return results.

In the hypothetical conditions, if I have two sentences as `hello world` and `hello hello world` then I am assuming the BRT would give me something like `[0.2,0.3,0]`, (0 for padding) and `[0.2,0.2,0.3]` and I can pass these two inside the `sklearn's` `cosine_similarity`.

How am I supposed to extract the embeddings the sentences to use them in the model? I found somewhere that it can be extracted like:

```
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
model = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
input_ids = torch.tensor(tokenizer.encode("Hello, my dog is cute")).unsqueeze(0)  # Batch size 1
outputs = model(input_ids)
last_hidden_states = outputs[0]  # The last hidden-state is the first element of the output tuple
Using Tensorflow:

import tensorflow as tf
from transformers import BertTokenizer, TFBertModel

tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
model = TFBertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
input_ids = tf.constant(tokenizer.encode("Hello, my dog is cute"))[None, :]  # Batch size 1
outputs = model(input_ids)
last_hidden_states = outputs[0]  # The last hidden-state is the first element of the output tuple
```

Is this the right way? Because I read somewhere that there are different type of embeddings that BERT offers.

**ALSO please do suggest any other method to find the text similarity**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to compare the embeddings of sentences the recommended way to do this with BERT is to use the value of the CLS token. This corresponds to the first token of the output (after the batch dimension).

```
last_hidden_states = outputs[0]
cls_embedding = last_hidden_states[0][0]
```

This will give you one embedding for the entire sentence. As you will have the same size embedding for each sentence you can then easily compute the cosine similarity.

If you do not get satisfactory results using the CLS token you can also try averaging the output embedding for each word in the sentence.

Comment: What if the sentences are of two  very different length? Actually, I want to find text similarity among Science (PCM- > Physics, chemistry ,maths) questions.

Comment: It doesn't matter. The CLS token can be seen as a summary of the sentence. It is also perfectly fine to average the word embeddings to generate a sentence embedding. See what works best for you.

Comment: @Deshwal . Can you mark this answer as correct since it appears to have answered your question.